# LDA with topicmodels (R), how can I see which topics different documents belong to, with document titles preserved?

Tags: r, topicmodels

I appreciate the answer from Ben here: LDA with topicmodels, how can I see which topics different documents belong to?

My question is: How do I preserve the document titles in the last step? For example:

Manually create three .txt documents in separate text files and store them in directory ~Desktop/nature_corpus

First document title: nature.txt

First document content: noun the natural world, Mother Nature, Mother Earth, the environment; wildlife, flora and fauna, the countryside; the universe, the cosmos.

Second document title: conservation.txt

Second document content: noun the conservation of tropical forests: preservation, protection, safeguarding, safekeeping; care, guardianship, husbandry, supervision; upkeep, maintenance, repair, restoration; ecology, environmentalism.

Third document title: bird.txt

Third document text: noun feeding the birds: fowl; chick, fledgling, nestling; informal feathered friend, birdie; budgie; (birds) technical avifauna.

```
#install.packages("tm")
#install.packages("topicmodels")
library(tm)
# Create DTM
#. The file path is a Mac file path.
corpus_nature_1 <- Corpus(DirSource("/Users/[home folder name]/Desktop/nature_corpus"),readerControl=list(reader=readPlain,language="en US")) 
corpus_nature_2 <- tm_map(corpus_nature_1,removeNumbers)
corpus_nature_3 <- tm_map(corpus_nature_2,content_transformer(tolower))
mystopwords <- c(stopwords(),"noun", "verb")
corpus_nature_4 <- tm_map(corpus_nature_3,removeWords, mystopwords)
corpus_nature_5 <- tm_map(corpus_nature_4,removePunctuation)
corpus_nature_6 <- tm_map(corpus_nature_5,stripWhitespace)
dtm_nature_1 <- DocumentTermMatrix(corpus_nature_6)

inspect(dtm_nature_1)
<<DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 3, terms: 42)>>
  Non-/sparse entries: 42/84
Sparsity           : 67%
Maximal term length: 16
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
Sample             :
  Terms
Docs               avifauna birdie birds budgie chick feathered feeding fledgling fowl mother
bird.txt                1      1     2      1     1         1       1         1    1      0
conservation.txt        0      0     0      0     0         0       0         0    0      0
nature.txt              0      0     0      0     0         0       0         0    0      2
```

The topic model run with topicmodels:

```
# Run topic model 2 topics
library(topicmodels)
topicmodels_LDA_nature_2 <- LDA(dtm_nature_1,2,method="Gibbs",control=list(seed=1),model=NULL)
terms(topicmodels_LDA_nature_2,3)
     Topic 1  Topic 2   
[1,] "birds"  "avifauna"
[2,] "mother" "birdie"  
[3,] "chick"  "budgie"
```

How can I retain the document titles (visible in the inspect(dtm_nature_1) line) here?

```
# Create CSV Matrix 2 topics
matrix_nature_2 <- as.data.frame(topicmodels_LDA_nature_2@gamma)
names(matrix_nature_2) <- c(1:2)
write.csv(matrix_nature_2,"matrix_nature_2.csv")

#. Rows in this table are documents, columns are topics.
    1           2
1   0.46875     0.53125
2   0.52238806  0.47761194
3   0.555555556 0.444444444
```

Thanks.

Comment: Care to provide a small, reproducible example?

Comment: Added, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I found this workaround, but would still be grateful if there was a neater solution. After running all of that code above, run this:

```
wordMatrix = as.data.frame( t(as.matrix(dtm_nature_1)) )
write.csv(wordMatrix,"dtm_nature_1.csv")
```

Then import the CSV file derived from this code (from above):

```
matrix_nature_2 <- as.data.frame(topicmodels_LDA_nature_2@gamma)
names(matrix_nature_2) <- c(1:2)
write.csv(matrix_nature_2,"matrix_nature_2.csv")
```

into excel, and then import the dtm_nature_1.csv into a second sheet of the excel file. Then copy the list of document titles (the column titles) from dtm_nature_1.csv and paste special transpose them into a clear column of the table for matrix_nature_2.csv.